# Convert .las file with LAStools in QGIS

Tags: qgis, lastools

I get the following error when trying to convert a .las file using las2txt with the LASTools plugin:
My system is set to UTF-8.

```
QGIS code revision: 4470baa1a3
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'las2txt' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS' : '', 'CPU64' : False, 'GUI' : False, 'INPUT_LASLAZ' : '\\\\scansrv.scanergy.local\\Folder Redirection\\ia\\My Documents\\Svavelsö GIS\\laserdata\\10C031_65925_6825_25.las', 'OUTPUT_GENERIC' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PARSE' : 'xyz', 'VERBOSE' : False }

LAStools command line
C:\LAStools\bin\las2txt -i "\\scansrv.scanergy.local\Folder Redirection\ia\My Documents\Svavelsö GIS\laserdata\10C031_65925_6825_25.las" -o "C:/Users/ia/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_10592c2961fb4f2b8e6471b587b96e4a/1f021684e02c4a05859479860806ffba/OUTPUT_GENERIC.file"
LAStools console output
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStools\las2txt.py", line 55, in processAlgorithm
LAStoolsUtils.runLAStools(commands, feedback)
File "C:/Users/ia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStoolsUtils.py", line 61, in runLAStools
feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 199: invalid start byte

Execution failed after 0.15 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'las2txt' finished
```

Comment: Paths like `\\\\scansrv.scanergy.local\\Folder Redirection\\ia\\My Documents\\Svavelsö GIS\\laserdata\\10C031_65925_6825_25.las`are always suspicious. Try with some simple path like `c:\data\test.las`. It may also be that las file contains text that is not in UTF-8.

Comment: Tried a shorter path but with the same results. It opens just fine in https://plas.io/, but there I can not export it to for example xyz. How would I go about finding out if the text in position 199 can be corrected?

Comment: Can I upload the file somewhere for assistance? What I need is the ground elevation as a xyz file so that I can read it into QGIS and generate a terrain model.

Comment: If you put the file available I can certainly have a look at it.

Comment: Please find the file in the below link: https://we.tl/t-d9qmXDuuEi